# ByteBuddy: Workaround for modifying schema of loaded class

Tags: byte-buddy

The issue: We generate classes using ByteBuddy, load them and at one point will need to add/remove fields without re-starting the application.

If I understand correctly, in Java it is not possible to modify the schema (add fields/methods) of a class already loaded into a class loader.

My question: As a workaround, would it be a possible/reasonable to create a new class loader when a such a conflict occurs - load all generated classes into the new class loader and close the old class loader?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a VM version of OpenJDK that supports such transformations, the [Dynamic Code Evolution VM](https://github.com/dcevm/dcevm).

For a regular VM, you can load a class in a new class loader. However, in this case no previous instance will be an instance of this altered class. You would need to recreate all instances. If this is feasible for you, this is an option.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!